# Capping values after a trigger level in a different variable

Tags: pandas, triggers

I wish to have the values of 'Original_Level' cap to the level where another column 'NS' hits a trigger (in this case abs(NS) >= 4 ).  This new column, 'Desired_Level', created while leaving the 'Original_Level' column unchanged.  The below df shows a cap of 13.122 and 50.887 when abs(NS) >= 4

```
In [36]:df

Out [36]:
Original_level     NS   Desired_Level
    9.566       -8.099    13.122
    10.629      -6.830    13.122
    11.810      -5.655    13.122
    13.122      -4.561    13.122
    14.580      -3.538    14.580
    16.200      -2.577    16.200
    18.000      -1.670    18.000
    20.000      -0.813    20.000
    22.000       0.000    22.000
    25.300       0.774    25.300
    29.095       1.511    29.095
    33.459       2.216    33.459
    38.478       2.891    38.478
    44.250       3.538    44.250
    50.887       4.160    50.887
    58.520       4.758    50.887
    67.299       5.335    50.887
```

I am looking for a generic solution, that works away from the lowest abs(NS) level in both directions to hit both the -4 and the +4 trigger.  If it not hit (which it might not be) then desired level is just original_level

An additional note, it will always be true that the abs(NS) continues to grow in size from the min(abs(NS)) level . . .in this case i have it as 0.0000 but may be some small number other than zero

Thanks in advance for any assistance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use [`clip`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.clip.html#pandas.Series.clip) for this, firstly find the indices of your upper and lower clip values using [`idxmax`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmax.html#pandas.Series.idxmax) and [`idxmin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.idxmin.html#pandas.Series.idxmin)and then pass these values as the params:

```
In [14]:
clip = 4
lower = df.loc[df['NS'] <= -clip, 'Original_level'].idxmax()
upper = df.loc[df['NS'] >= clip, 'Original_level'].idxmin()
df['Original_level'] = df['Original_level'].clip(df.loc[lower, 'Original_level'], df.loc[upper, 'Original_level'])
df

Out[14]:
    Original_level     NS  Desired_Level
0           13.122 -8.099         13.122
1           13.122 -6.830         13.122
2           13.122 -5.655         13.122
3           13.122 -4.561         13.122
4           14.580 -3.538         14.580
5           16.200 -2.577         16.200
6           18.000 -1.670         18.000
7           20.000 -0.813         20.000
8           22.000  0.000         22.000
9           25.300  0.774         25.300
10          29.095  1.511         29.095
11          33.459  2.216         33.459
12          38.478  2.891         38.478
13          44.250  3.538         44.250
14          50.887  4.160         50.887
15          50.887  4.758         50.887
16          50.887  5.335         50.887
```

Comment: Ed, I tried this on my example data and it worked, but when I transferred this to my "production" data it did not.  The difference being that I had performed a groupby on the production data data.  Can you provide some insight if the sample data had been grouped by date and city (for example). Thank you again.  John

Comment: Sorry you're trying to apply to a groupby object? Does it work after calling `reset_index()`? really you should post a new question as chaning the requirements loses context for the changes.

Comment: I posted as you suggested, Just added the words "_after groupBy" to the end of this subject line